# How to find the total number of exchanges?

Tags: combinatorics

Given n objects held by n people, how to find the total number of valid exchanges, where a valid exchange means that all persons hold different objects after the exchange?

eg for 4 objects 1 2 3 4: valid exchanges are:

2 1 4 3

2 3 4 1

2 4 1 3

3 1 4 2

3 4 1 2

3 4 2 1

4 1 2 3

4 3 1 2

4 3 2 1

Therefor the total number of valid exchanges are 9.

Comment: There are $!n$ such "exchanges" which are more commonly known as [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: I don't really get it. Why aren't there any configurations where the first one is holding the first object? For example after 4 3 1 2 you could exhange so that the new one is 1 2 4 3

Comment: what does !n mean, is it the same as n! ?

Comment: No, $!n$ is not the same as $n!$.  Read the link I posted in my comment above for the wikipedia article or read the answers in the linked post that I closed this as a duplicate of.  Reading the word aloud, $!n$ is read as "*n subfactorial*" which is different than $n!$ which is "*n factorial.*"  The notation $!n$ is used to notate the solution to exactly the problem you are asking to count.  Methods of actually calculating the values are given again in both links I provided.

Comment: @MattiP. it is not a sequence, these are the possible exchanges after 1 2 3 4. 1 2 4 3 is not poossible because 1 and 2 are with the same person.

Comment: @MattiP. you should read the links as well.  Derangements are permutations with no fixed points.  That is to say, if $\pi$ is a permutation it is a derangment iff $\pi(i)\neq i$ for all $i$.  Of course, compositions of derangements are not necessarily going to be derangements themselves (though they could be).

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you.

Comment: Okay I guess I misunderstood the problem statement.